# Combobox doesn't display the populated values

Tags: sqlite, tkinter, python-3.8

I created a combobox to show a list of values out of a sqlite database.
If I sent the values to the combobox, the list will shown. The problem is, that the field will not filled with the first value and stay empty until I select on item of out of the drop menu.
Could I set a value to be displayed directly?

Here my code snippet:

```
    self.e_business = ttk.Combobox(address_frame, width = 40)
    self.e_business.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(5,20), pady=(15,5), sticky='WE')
```

The function which send the values:

```
def show_name_search(self, event):
        ...
        widget = event.widget
        selection = widget.curselection()
        indName = widget.get(selection[0])
        print(indName)
        print("selktierter Wert: {}".format(indName))
        
        self.realName.set(indName)
        
        connection = sqlite3.connect(select_connect_db)
        print('Database connected.')
        with connection: 
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT number, type, prio, id, uniqueid FROM numbers WHERE realName='"+indName+"';")
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            print(data)
            cache = []
            for row in data:
                cache.append(row[0])                    
                self.e_business['values'] = cache
```

The cache list looks like:

```
CACHE: ['081191310912', '071109131090', '01754123353']
```

Comment: Try putting `self.e_business['values'] = cache` outside the loop. Change your query to `cursor.execute("SELECT number, type, prio, id, uniqueid FROM numbers WHERE realName=?;",(indName,))`, so there is no SQL injection

Comment: @Cool Cloud, no change, if I put the self.e_business['values'] = cache outside the loop. Still an empty entry in my combobox, until I select one value. Thanks for the second hint, I have changed even I found the colon inside the brackets strange (indName, ). What does this stands for?

Comment: Comma inside the bracket makes it a tuple as parameters have to be tuples. Try to define `cache` outside the function in `__init__()`? Like `self.cache = []` and try the same out.

Comment: The cache values are populated to the combobox, but shown in drop down only. I would like to see the first value without select the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the list in the `__init__()` and then populate inside the function, like:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.cache = []
... # Rest of codes

def show_name_search(self,event):
....# Rest of codes
    for row in data:
        self.cache.append(row[0])                    

    self.e_business['values'] = self.cache # Set the value to the new list
    self.e_business.current(0) # Set the first item of the list as current item
```

To set the item to the current item, you can use `current()` and the index of the item to be set first. Note that the indentation levels will change according to your class.

Comment: Doesn't work even worst, because I get no result in the combobox. Totally empty.

Comment: I run now in another problem. Some fields in my database table are None. So I get this error message from the current(0): return self.tk.call(self._w, "current", newindex)
_tkinter.TclError: Index 0 out of range - How can I prevent this?

Comment: Maybe ask a new question. Error might mean that list is empty.

Comment: I think this is related to this point and your answer with current(0). with my query I will update several comboboxes, but som values are empty. Let say phone numbers from office, mobile and home. Some contacts have ony home and mobile but no business work number. This arise this errors, if I would like to update the comboboy, but position 0 is not exist.

Comment: Not sure, but I think position 0 always exists if the list is non empty. I guess the list is empty in your case, just verify

Comment: closed this question and rise another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65528985/tkinter-callback-through-an-error-index-0-out-of-range